# Error while merging docx files into single pdf using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, docx

I used a Google Apps script [code](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/10/merging-multiple-pdf-files-as-a-single-pdf-file-using-google-apps-script/) proposed by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) to merge multiple PDF files into one. My requirements are:

> 1. Get file id
> 2. Check if it is pdf or docx
> 3. If it is docx, convert it into pdf and then merge it

Here is the modified snippet:

```
async function newMain() {
  // Retrieve PDF data.
 
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your-folder-id")
  var urls = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue().toString().split(",");  //split the urls joined by commas 
  const ids = urls.map((url) => {
  const matches = url.match(/\/file\/d\/([^\/]+)\/edit/); //get file id from urls
  return matches ? [matches[1]] : [];
});

  const data = ids.map(([id]) => {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  const mimeType = file.getMimeType();

  // Check if the file is a DOCX
if (mimeType === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
  
  
   var blob = file.getBlob();
   var tempfile = Drive.Files.insert({}, blob, {convert:true});
   var id = tempfile["id"];
  
   var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
   var body = doc.getBody();
   var text = body.getText();
   var pdfFile = destinationFolder.createFile(`temp.pdf`, text, "application/pdf"); 

    // Get the PDF content
   const pdfData = pdfFile.getBlob().getBytes();
   Drive.Files.remove(id);
    // Remove the temporary PDF file
   DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
   return new Uint8Array(pdfData);

  } else if (mimeType === 'application/pdf') {
    // File is already a PDF, fetch its content
    return new Uint8Array(file.getBlob().getBytes());
  } 
});



  // Load pdf-lib
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));

  // Merge PDFs.
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < pdfData.getPageCount(); j++) {
      const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [j]);
      pdfDoc.addPage(page);
    }
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create a PDF file.
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample2.pdf"));
  file.moveTo(destinationFolder);
 
 }
```

when I run it, I receive the following error:

> Error: Failed to parse PDF document (line:368 col:0 offset=18311): No PDF header found
> e
> e
> e.parseHeader
> eval
> eval
> eval
> eval
> i
> e.parseDocument

Due to my beginner skills, I am unable to resolve or improve it, any guidance in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which line is line 368?

Comment: line 368 is not in apps script code, it refers to line in pdf library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- If your values of `ids` are valid file IDs of DOCX files, in your script, I think that `pdfData` is not the PDF data. In your script, the text data is retrieved and the retrieved text data is saved as a text file without the PDF data. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
async function newMain() {
  // Retrieve PDF data.
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your-folder-id")
  var urls = sheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue().toString().split(",");  //split the urls joined by commas 
  const ids = urls.map((url) => {
    const matches = url.match(/\/file\/d\/([^\/]+)\/edit/); //get file id from urls
    return matches ? [matches[1]] : [];
  });


  // --- I modifieid the below script.
  const data = ids.flatMap(([id]) => {
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    const mimeType = file.getMimeType();
    if (mimeType === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
      var blob = file.getBlob();
      var tempfile = Drive.Files.insert({}, blob, { convert: true });
      const pdfData = DriveApp.getFileById(tempfile.id).getBlob().getBytes();
      Drive.Files.remove(tempfile.id);
      return new Uint8Array(pdfData);
    } else if (mimeType === 'application/pdf') {
      return new Uint8Array(file.getBlob().getBytes());
    }
    return [];
  });
  // ---


  // Load pdf-lib
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));

  // Merge PDFs.
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < pdfData.getPageCount(); j++) {
      const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [j]);
      pdfDoc.addPage(page);
    }
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create a PDF file.
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample2.pdf"));
  file.moveTo(destinationFolder);
}
```

- In this modified script, if the values of `ids` are valid file IDs of DOCX files, the DOCX files are converted to Google Document, and the Google Document is converted to PDF data. And then, each PDF data is merged.
- I added a process for the files without `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` and `application/pdf`, because I cannot know your actual file IDs.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your values of `ids` are valid file IDs of DOCX files. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Because when I tested the sample file IDs with `ids`, all PDF files were merged. I apologize for this situation. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. When I saw your new question, I would like to try to understand your new question. By the way, when I saw your URL, it seemed that the number of pages is 5. And about `you want me to post it as new question?`, it's yes.  If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: yes please, this url has more than 300 pages but merged pdf did not merge all pages of this docx file `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-yFHs6DJfRJA9dLzy0yed3uLW4_XdNxD/edit`

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. I thought that I could understand your new issue. In that case, it is required to modify the script for converting the URL to ID, and also it is required to modify the script for merging PDF data. So, in this case, I think that your new issue is different from your this question. So, can you post it as a new question? And, I believe that it will be useful for other users. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thank you, I added a question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77551475/javascript-runtime-error-while-merging-docx-files-into-pdf`