# JavaScript runtime error while merging docx files into pdf

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, merge

This is the continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548691/error-while-merging-docx-files-into-single-pdf-using-google-apps-script/77550213#77550213) where [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) proposed a solution to merge docx files into a pdf. The following code merges docx files into pdf:

```
async function newMain() {
  // Retrieve PDF data.
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your-folder-id")
  var urls = sheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue().toString().split(",");  //split the urls joined by commas 
    const ids = urls.map((url) => {
    const matches = url.match(/\/file\/d\/([^\/]+)\/edit/); //get file id from urls
    return matches ? [matches[1]] : [];
  });

    const data = ids.flatMap(([id]) => {
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    const mimeType = file.getMimeType();
    if (mimeType === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
      var blob = file.getBlob();
      var tempfile = Drive.Files.insert({}, blob, { convert: true });
      const pdfData = DriveApp.getFileById(tempfile.id).getBlob().getBytes();
      Drive.Files.remove(tempfile.id);
      return new Uint8Array(pdfData);
    } else if (mimeType === 'application/pdf') {
      return new Uint8Array(file.getBlob().getBytes());
    }
    return [];
  });



  // Load pdf-lib
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));

  // Merge PDFs.
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < pdfData.getPageCount(); j++) {
      const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [j]);
      pdfDoc.addPage(page);
    }
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create a PDF file.
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample2.pdf"));
  file.moveTo(destinationFolder);
}
```

However, when I plug the following URLs:

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-yFHs6DJfRJA9dLzy0yed3uLW4_XdNxD/edit,https://drive.google.com/file/d/16-nyhNGEUpLzT1p1--MseDRO5uzAPdRa/edit,https://drive.google.com/file/d/15VHdNbEJpsEPMRIvzwUJNRA5sZkIdoTO/edit,https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dNHeu-kncSC6f6Dm4DscCnjNejh-6FT1/edit

It shows the following error message:

**`The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly.`**

I believe this occurs when the following line is executed:

```
var file = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample2.pdf"));
```

Any guidance to solve this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, the URL like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileId}/edit` is retrieved. In your showing URLs, `https://docs.google.com/document/d/{fileId}/edit` is included. In this case, your script cannot retrieve the file ID from the URL. I think that this is the 1st issue of your script.
- When the large PDF data is merged, it seems that the showing script for merging PDF data cannot be used. In this case, it is required to also modify the script for merging PDF data. [Ref (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/10/merging-multiple-pdf-files-as-a-single-pdf-file-using-google-apps-script/) I think that this is the 2nd issue of your script.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set `sheet` and your folder ID.

```js
async function newMain() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please declare the variable of "sheet".

  // Retrieve PDF data.
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your-folder-id")
  var urls = sheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue().toString().split(",");

  const ids = urls.map(url => [url.split("/")[5]]); // Modified

  const data = ids.flatMap(([id]) => {
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    const mimeType = file.getMimeType();
    if (mimeType === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
      var blob = file.getBlob();
      var tempfile = Drive.Files.insert({}, blob, { convert: true });
      const pdfData = DriveApp.getFileById(tempfile.id).getBlob().getBytes();
      Drive.Files.remove(tempfile.id);
      return new Uint8Array(pdfData);
    } else if (mimeType === 'application/pdf') {
      return new Uint8Array(file.getBlob().getBytes());
    }
    return [];
  });

  // Load pdf-lib
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));

  // Modified
  // Merge PDFs.
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    const pages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, pdfData.getPageIndices());
    pages.forEach(page => pdfDoc.addPage(page));
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create a PDF file.
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample2.pdf"));
  file.moveTo(destinationFolder);
}
```

- When I tested this modified script using your showing URLs of `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-yFHs6DJfRJA9dLzy0yed3uLW4_XdNxD/edit,https://drive.google.com/file/d/16-nyhNGEUpLzT1p1--MseDRO5uzAPdRa/edit,https://drive.google.com/file/d/15VHdNbEJpsEPMRIvzwUJNRA5sZkIdoTO/edit,https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dNHeu-kncSC6f6Dm4DscCnjNejh-6FT1/edit` in cell "B2", I confirmed that a PDF file including 330 pages is created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I apologize, there is a line in the script `const matches = url.match(/\/d\/([^\/]+)\/edit/);` that gets id from url.

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. From your showing URLs, I think that `const ids = urls.map(url => [url.split("/")[5]])` can be also used for retrieving the file IDs from the URLs. But, please use your expected script.

Comment: thank you, it works as required, can you please tell me what was the issue in the previous script that it did not merge large files?

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `can you please tell me what was the issue in the previous script that it did not merge large files?`, it seems that when the method `getPageIndices` is used for merging PDF data, the large PDF data can be merged without errors. [Ref](https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdfdocument#getpageindices) This is different from your initial script. If this was not a useful explanation, I apologize. Also, I updated my blog.